# Jfrog C++ Setup Conan packages

Tags: artifactory, bintray, conan

I have to upload the C++ Conan Packages 10gb in to JFrog Community edition[CE] jfrog will defaultly support the packages or have to integrate with PostgreSQL Server.

Comment: Please check out how to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask It is unclear what problem you are trying to solve and what problems you ran into.

Comment: Jfrog will defaultly comes with Derby SQL Server but it not supporting to upload 10GB Packages it is limited up to 100mb only am stucked with integrating the PostgresQl Server Instead of derby SQL.

Comment: The upload limitation should be only on the UI. You could use the REST APi to upload with curl, or better and faster with the jfrog cli. 
https://jfrog.com/getcli/
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UploadingFiles
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF6X/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-Example-DeployinganArtifact